# Do you need a Nintendo Online subscription to play Rocket League's online modes?

Tags: rocket-league, nintendo-switch-online

I know Nintendo Online isn't required to get the game, but is it required to play the online modes?  The servers are run by Psyonix so I would assume no, but you never know with Nintendo.  I don't have a Switch myself yet so I can't test it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Nintendo Online is not required. I played Rocket League online with my Switch before I had a Nintendo Online subscription. You do need to create an account with Epic Games, but that is free and easy to do.

Answer (score 4):

According to a [blog post](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/rocket-league-free-to-play--seasons--new-ranks--and-more/) on Rocket League's website (posted in 2020 when the free-to-play update was announced), a paid subscription for Nintendo Switch Online services is not required to play online for Rocket League

> PlayStation Plus on PlayStation 4 and Nintendo Switch Online will no longer be required for online play on those platforms.